# How to animate the colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, colorbar

I have an animation where the range of the data varies a lot. I would like to have a `colorbar` which tracks the max and the min of the data (i.e. I would like it not to be fixed). The question is how to do this.

Ideally I would like the `colorbar` to be on its own axis.

I have tried the following four things

### 1. Naive approach

The problem: A new colorbar is plottet for each frame

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An animated image
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(x) + np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

frames = []

for i in range(10):
    x       += 1
    curVals  = f(x, y)
    vmax     = np.max(curVals)
    vmin     = np.min(curVals)
    levels   = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 200, endpoint = True)
    frame    = ax.contourf(curVals, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, levels=levels)
    cbar     = fig.colorbar(frame)
    frames.append(frame.collections)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

### 2. Adding to the images

Changing the for loop above to

```
initFrame = ax.contourf(f(x,y)) 
cbar      = fig.colorbar(initFrame)
for i in range(10):
    x       += 1
    curVals  = f(x, y)
    vmax     = np.max(curVals)      
    vmin     = np.min(curVals)      
    levels   = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 200, endpoint = True)
    frame    = ax.contourf(curVals, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, levels=levels)
    cbar.set_clim(vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax)
    cbar.draw_all()
    frames.append(frame.collections + [cbar])
```

The problem: This raises

```
AttributeError: 'Colorbar' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

### 3. Plotting on its own axis

The problem: The `colorbar` is not updated.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 """
 An animated image
 """
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib.animation as animation

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
 ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)


 def f(x, y):
     return np.exp(x) + np.sin(y)

 x = np.linspace(0, 1, 120)
 y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

 frames = []

 for i in range(10):
     x       += 1
     curVals  = f(x, y)
     vmax     = np.max(curVals)
     vmin     = np.min(curVals)
     levels   = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 200, endpoint = True)
     frame    = ax1.contourf(curVals, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, levels=levels)
     cbar     = fig.colorbar(frame, cax=ax2) # Colorbar does not update
     frames.append(frame.collections)

 ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames, blit=False)

 plt.show()
```

### A combination of 2. and 4.

The problem: The `colorbar` is constant.

A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562176/matplotlib-animation-with-changing-colorbar-and-title-for-each-frame), but it looks like the OP is satisfied with a fixed `colorbar`.

Comment: How tied are you to an ArtistAnimation?  I'm not sure how to do it that way, but I could give you an example using a FuncAnimation instead...

Comment: As far as I remember, I started using ArtistAnimation as I had problems animating some text acting as titles with FuncAnimation. Other than that, I am open to switch back to FuncAnimation. An example would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While I'm not sure how to do this specifically using an `ArtistAnimation`, using a `FuncAnimation` is fairly straightforward.  If I make the following modifications to your "naive" version 1 it works.

**Modified Version 1**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# I like to position my colorbars this way, but you don't have to
div = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = div.append_axes('right', '5%', '5%')

def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(x) + np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

frames = []
for i in range(10):
    x       += 1
    curVals  = f(x, y)
    frames.append(curVals)

cv0 = frames[0]
cf = ax.contourf(cv0, 200)
cb = fig.colorbar(cf, cax=cax)
tx = ax.set_title('Frame 0')

def animate(i):
    arr = frames[i]
    vmax     = np.max(arr)
    vmin     = np.min(arr)
    levels   = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 200, endpoint = True)
    cf = ax.contourf(arr, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, levels=levels)
    cax.cla()
    fig.colorbar(cf, cax=cax)
    tx.set_text('Frame {0}'.format(i))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10)

plt.show()
```

The main difference is that I do the levels calculations and contouring in a function instead of creating a list of artists.  The colorbar works because you can clear the axes from the previous frame and redo it every frame.

Doing this redo is necessary when using `contour` or `contourf`, because you can't just dynamically change the data.  However, as you have plotted so many contour levels and the result looks smooth, I think you may be better off using `imshow` instead - it means you can actually just use the same artist and change the data, and the colorbar updates itself automatically.  It's also much faster!

**Better Version**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# I like to position my colorbars this way, but you don't have to
div = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = div.append_axes('right', '5%', '5%')

def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(x) + np.sin(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

# This is now a list of arrays rather than a list of artists
frames = []
for i in range(10):
    x       += 1
    curVals  = f(x, y)
    frames.append(curVals)

cv0 = frames[0]
im = ax.imshow(cv0, origin='lower') # Here make an AxesImage rather than contour
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
tx = ax.set_title('Frame 0')

def animate(i):
    arr = frames[i]
    vmax     = np.max(arr)
    vmin     = np.min(arr)
    im.set_data(arr)
    im.set_clim(vmin, vmax)
    tx.set_text('Frame {0}'.format(i))
    # In this version you don't have to do anything to the colorbar,
    # it updates itself when the mappable it watches (im) changes

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. There are no problems with overlapping text in this example either (as was the reason why I changed to `ArtistAnimation`). Using `imshow` would of course be preferable, but I'm stuck with `contourf` in my case due to a non-rectangular grid.

Comment: @Ajean, would you know how to do the same with logarithmic color scale (norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()) and fixed vmin/vmax values (fixed colorbar)?

Comment: @TheoryX I believe that if you want the LogNorm (and hence the colormapping) to have a fixed vmin and vmax, all you need to do is pass it in to the initial call to imshow, then don't adjust the `clim` inside the animate function.  That results in a fixed colorbar though, so not quite what this particular question was after.