# Matplotlib animation with different title for each frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have a sequence of 2D arrays which I would like to make an animation of. I would like to customize some of the frames, e.g. by adding different titles.

```
N_TIME_STEPS=100
records = get_records()
# records is a 250 X 250 X N_TIME_STEPS ndarray
ims = []
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(N_TIME_STEPS):
    count_map = records[:, :, i]
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(f"step {i}")
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$k$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\tau_{0}$')
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    im = ax.imshow(count_map, cmap="inferno", origin='lower', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1])
    plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    ims.append([im])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=100, blit=False, repeat_delay=1000)
```

This doesn't work. The title of all frames is "step 99"

Matplotlib helpfully supplies the following warning

```
Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance
```

But when I try this advice and use

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, label=str(i))
```

I get an unexplained

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594887/how-to-update-plot-title-with-matplotlib-using-animation) question does not help me as blit is set to False and I want the title outside of the plot. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562176/matplotlib-animation-with-changing-colorbar-and-title-for-each-frame) question is also irrelevant

Comment: Each axes has a single title. Hence there is no way to have the title change with an `ArtistAnimation`. You could use different `ax.text()` elements instead. Or you use a `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: Can’t you change the text attribute of the title?